# Changing the Environment Variables of a ProcessBuilder after the process started

Tags: java, environment-variables, processbuilder

I want to set Environment variables of a SubProcess, built via a ProcessBuilder, after it started. The following code does not work:

```
ProcessBuilder pb  = new ProcessBuilder("cscript.exe", "test.vbs");
Process p = pb.start();
pb.environment().put("test", "1");
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot do that. Process builder environments are isolated and not mutable after starting them.

> Two ProcessBuilder instances always contain **independent** process environments, so changes to the returned map will never be reflected in any other ProcessBuilder instance or the values returned by System.getenv.
>
> Subsequent modifications to this process builder will not affect the returned Process.

If you're interested in passing information to the process **after** starting it, use the `OutputStream` for the process and write to it. The process should read from its input stream and process the communication from the caller. [More help](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

```
OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();  
// write data to this stream and read it on the other end.
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that this is not a limitation of `ProcessBuilder` or Java, but that this is due to the nature how operating systems work in general - and that it can't be any other way.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible, see ProcessBuilder.start API: *... Subsequent modifications to this process builder will not affect the returned Process.*